# jQuery: Remove Parent Div if element inside does not have a class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a grid with 3 columns each column share the same `div class`. Inside of each column is a span with a class of `class="simplefavorite-button"`OR `class="simplefavorite-button.active"`. So the markup looks like this:

```
<div class="vc_grid-item">
  <div class="some-class">content</div>
<span class="simplefavorite-button">heartbutton</span>
</div>

<div class="vc_grid-item">
  <div class="some-class">content</div>
<span class="simplefavorite-button">heartbutton</span>
</div>

<div class="vc_grid-item">
  <div class="some-class">content</div>
<span class="simplefavorite-button.active">heartbutton</span>
</div>
```

So what I am trying to do is remove the upper most div for any column with the class **class='vc_grid-item**' if the element within that parent class does not equal class **class="simplefavorite-button.active"**

Below is the code I have tried. But have not had any success. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

My Code

```
jQuery('simplefavorite-button.active').each(function () {
    jQuery('span').not(this).closest('.vc_grid-item').hide();
});
```

Comment: Also, the jQuery above works. BUT it removes all of the parent elements. I only want the ones that do not have the class of simplefavorite-button.active

Comment: Why not checking on the other class ".simplefavorite-button" ? is it a pattern? I mean if it's not simplefavorite-button.active then it must be simplefavorite-button?? right

Answer (score 3):

Try this out.

```js
jQuery('.simplefavorite-button').not(".active").each(function () {
    jQuery(this).closest('.vc_grid-item').hide();
});
```